# XML load is slow. Using text() when reading XML file with attribute-centric mapping

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sqlxml

I am reading in an XML file into the database. It works fine however it is very slow. I was wondering if I can use `text()` in order to speed the process up similarly to the solution in this post: [Xml select query xpath is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289773/xml-select-query-xpath-is-slow).
My problem however is that the solution is for XML with element-centric mapping while I have attribute-centric mapping so I'm not sure how to use `text()` in my case.

The XML looks like this

```XML
<Level1>
    <Level2 name="l2_name">
        <Level3 name="l3_name">
            <Level4 name="l4_name">
                <Level5 name="l5_name">
                    <Level6_1 name="l6_1_name" value="l6_1_value"/>
                    <Level6_2 name="l6_2_name" value="l6_2_value"/>
```

I am using the following code

```SQL
declare @x xml

select @x = c1 
from openrowset(bulk 'd:\file.xml', single_blob) as table1(c1);

select
    c.value('@name', 'varchar(20)') as [col1],
    c2.value('@name', 'varchar(20)') as [col2],
    c3.value('@name', 'varchar(20)') as [col3],
    c4.value('@name', 'varchar(20)') as [col4],
    c5_1.value('@name', 'varchar(20)') as [col5],
    c5_1.value('@value', 'varchar(20)') as [col6],
    c5_2.value('@name', 'varchar(20)') as [col7],
    c5_2.value('@value', 'varchar(20)') as [col8],
from @x.nodes('Level1/Level2') as t(c)
cross apply c.nodes('Level3') as t2(c2)
cross apply c2.nodes('Level4') as t3(c3)
cross apply c3.nodes('Level5') as t4(c4)
cross apply c4.nodes('Level6_1') as t5_1(c5_1)
cross apply c4.nodes('Level6_2') as t5_2(c5_2)
```

The file I am reading is 13MB and it takes 3.5 hours to read it in.

Comment: Sometimes old style `sp_xml_preparedocument` works faster.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't load an XML file into the database, it *parses* the file and extracts the attributes without importing the file. The question you linked to is a completely different case - it loads XML data from an XML field where the data was already parsed, shredded and stored as XML elements. The linked query shows the difference between `.value` and `text()` when working with elements. Your query though reads *attributes*

Comment: Try creating a staging table with an xml-typed field that's covered by an index. Load the XML text you want into that field and query the indexed field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to test on so many rows as you have, I'll give you this script to try out ([fiddle<>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=33620f72b04bbdc5f3f7295a93665834)):

```sql
DECLARE @x XML=N'
<Level1><Level2 name="l2_name"><Level3 name="l3_name">
<Level4 name="l4_name"><Level5 name="l5_name">
<Level6 name="l6_name" value="l6_value"/>
<Level6 name="l6_name" value="l6_value"/>
</Level5></Level4></Level3></Level2></Level1>';

SELECT
    x.n.value('../../../../@name', 'varchar(20)') as [col1],
    x.n.value('../../../@name', 'varchar(20)') as [col2],
    x.n.value('../../@name', 'varchar(20)') as [col3],
    x.n.value('../@name', 'varchar(20)') as [col4],
    x.n.value('./@name', 'varchar(20)') as [col5]
FROM
    @x.nodes('/Level1/Level2/Level3/Level4/Level5/Level6') AS x(n);
```

This would explicitly query for `Level6` nodes, then backtrack for the parents' attribute values. This is quite likely faster than cross applying queries for each individual `LevelN` element.

---

Updated, for elements in level 6 with different names and assuming only one such element of each name appears as a child of level 5:

```sql
DECLARE @x_2 XML=N'<Level1>
    <Level2 name="l2_name">
        <Level3 name="l3_name">
            <Level4 name="l4_name">
                <Level5 name="l5_name">
                    <Level6_1 name="l6_1_name" value="l6_1_value"/>
                    <Level6_2 name="l6_2_name" value="l6_2_value"/>
                    </Level5></Level4></Level3></Level2></Level1>';

SELECT
    x.n.value('../../../@name', 'varchar(20)') as [col1],
    x.n.value('../../@name', 'varchar(20)') as [col2],
    x.n.value('../@name', 'varchar(20)') as [col3],
    x.n.value('./@name', 'varchar(20)') as [col4],
    x.n.value('(./Level6_1/@name)[1]', 'varchar(20)') as [col5],
    x.n.value('(./Level6_2/@name)[1]', 'varchar(20)') as [col6]
FROM
    @x_2.nodes('/Level1/Level2/Level3/Level4/Level5') AS x(n);
```

This selects nodes on level 5, backtracks to parents for parent attributes, then selects child elements based on name. Selects the first such element using `[1]` selector.

Comment: Right.  Go to the deepest level in Xpath (6), then use relative paths back to the parents to avoid the cross joins.  That would also be my first attempt at coding this.

Comment: @TT. Thanks for the answer. How would I use you query however if I had two distinct records on level 6? Should I still `apply` it from a second `@xnodes`? I edited my questions to display it.

Comment: @Alex.S I've updated the answer, but please avoid changing your question each time.

Comment: @Alex.S Is it faster, and fast enough?

Comment: @TT. Sorry was away. It's faster but not by much. I guess it is what it is with XML. Thanks

Comment: @Alex.S If you have the XML in a table, perhaps with XML indexing it gets faster still (although there's the load time to factor in as well).

Comment: @Alex.S I've recently come to read that using [`OPENXML`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openxml-transact-sql) can be much more performant. Perhaps you should try it out. Some examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/examples-using-openxml).